# Does hair/beard length affect on skin oil production?

Tags: acne, oil-of-skin

I like to know if someone shaves his beard or cuts his hair, will this reduce his skin oil production? And conversely will long hair/beard cause more skin oil?

Totally, is there any relation between hair/beard length and facial acne?